# How can I create an alias for a class, globally, in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Right now, I am using "string" to enumerate a list of equipment slots on a character.
I am also using "string" to enumerate the class type that the item can be equipped on.

This makes all my methods where I get, remove, generate, etc. items involve having two string parameters that is an equipment slot and class type.

What I really would like is to use 2 classes so that I have 2 strongly typed concepts for the slot and class_type.

The problem is that string is a sealed class and thus I cannot extend it!

A solution I conceived is to use "using SlotType = string;" as alias but I don't know how to have this work GLOBALLY.

How do you define a global alias for a class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C# you can create a type alias using "using". [Because obviously that term needed a 3rd meanings in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive) ;) However 'the scope of a using directive is limited to the file in which it appears.', so it would not apply globally.

There is another option - create a subclass. For example,

```
public class ListOfIntegers : List<int>{
  //Nothing to do here.
}
```

would give you a sort-off-alias for `List<int>` that applies everywhere ListOfIntegers is given as Project Reference.

As for not being able to extend something: Just encapsulate it instead.

```
public class TypedString1 {
  public value;
}

public class TypedString2 {
  public value;
}
```

But you may want to set it up so that string overloads are used for stuff like Equality and ToString calls. Also propably a implicit cast to string to make it easier to use.

Comment: Hmmm, encapsulation might be good enough! I guess I could make an Attribute to render it as if it was a string (in the Inspector). I shall wait for other suggestions, else accept thisone. Thanks friend!